# Mini Cart for Luna Theme

Tags: cart, bigcartel

This is my website - http://www.afternoons.com.au/ - using Big Cartel, Luna Theme. At the moment, when products are placed in the cart, the cart doesn't show any number or dollar value and I can't find how to edit this for Luna theme. 
I know other big cartel themes have mini carts..is this something that can be adapted to luna theme and if so, how?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you try contacting Big Cartel support about this issue? I'm seeing your cart display the totals without any problems. http://www.bigcartel.com/contact

Comment: Hi Nick, the cart totals on the cart page are no problem..I would just love the cart in the main nav to display the total as well, so customers can view that as they look around the store. I've asked big cartel help about this but there isn't too much they can tell me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this by heading to Customize Design > Advanced > Layout in your admin, and scroll down to find the long line of code that ends with this:

```
<li {% if page.full_url contains '/cart' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/cart">Cart</a></li>
```

Change that to the following, and you're all set:

```
<li {% if page.full_url contains '/cart' %}class="selected"{% endif %}><a href="/cart">Cart {{ cart.subtotal | money_with_sign }}</a></li>
```

If you want to use the number of items in the cart instead of the cart subtotal, you can replace `{{ cart.subtotal | money_with_sign }}` with `{{ cart.item_count }}`

Comment: Thank you, Nick! Is there a way of showing the item count instead of the money value? For eg: cart (1) ? Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, I edited my original response with how to do that.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much Nick! Really appreciated.